# JavaScript addEventListner form within a form

Tags: javascript

I have a Form made up of multiple fields.

Within this form, I am adding two new fields that I like to be able to keep adding values to which get submitted to the database.

The primary form is used to populate a city name, address, etc. the new fields are used to populate event names and dates.

For example,
I add Manchester as the city and then I'd like to add as many events to Manchester as I like.

At the moment I have a JavaScript `addEventListener` setup for the submit button of the primary form which will `POST` all for the fields i specify, but this refreshes the page every time i `SUBMIT`

I need to keep the city name field populated so that each event added will contain the city name and the additional `event name` and `event date` fields.

Ultimately I want a table with `City`, `EventName` and `EventDate` and a table with the city details.

So I'm wondering how i do this with JavaScript to only submit the `city`, `event name` and `event date`?

I tried to create a new form within a form and reference that with a different js file, but this triggers when the primary form `submit` is triggered.

```
var event_form = document.getElementById("add-event");
event_form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validated(this)) {
        this.classList.add("was-validated");
        var e_eventname = document.getElementById("project-event-name").value;
        var e_eventdate = document.getElementById("project-event-date").value;
        //var e_cityname = document.getElementById("city-name").value;

        const csrftoken = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;

        const formdata = new FormData();

        formdata.append("event_name", e_eventname);
        formdata.append("event_date", e_eventdate);
        //formdata.append("city_name", e_name);


        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/apps/add_event");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            window.location.reload();
        };
    }
})
```

So i somehow need to setup the JS to trigger on a seperate button that will only `POST` the specific fields.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with python? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Django is a web framework that runs on Python. This is a Django form running on Python with  JavaScript triggers.

Comment: @JacksWastedLife can somebody who *only* has knowledge of Python and/or Django answer your question?

Comment: No, but someone with Django/python might have experienced the same issue. Removing the tag reduces the exposure.
The original post was edited, to remove Django from the question - which is annoying as there could be a better way to resolve this problem just using django.

Comment: The tags are to show the question to the correct users. Not just to increase exposure. People who have used Java or PHP as a backend might have also experienced the same issue but you've not tagged either of these. And you shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, but i'm not using PHP or Java, I AM using Python and Django with JS

Comment: And what does it matter if you use Python or PHP? You've not shared any of the backend code. It's irrelevant in which language it is and which framework is used.

Comment: No but i did include it in the original question, until it was removed

Comment: There was never any backend code in the question. See [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69872924/revisions). The only thing you included was the word "Django" which is not actionable in order to get an answer.

Comment: I meant that i had specified Django which is a web framework for Python. Hence the tags for Python and Django. Someone with Django experience might know a better way. So if i include backend code does that mean i can tag it with Django and Python?

Comment: Only if it's relevant to the question. You shouldn't include irrelevant code. We want a [mcve] with questions, not just all the code you happen to have.

Comment: Ok. Well, i suppose the time will tell if someone who only knows JavaScript feels this is enough information to provide advice without me having to provide details of the web framework. It might make things easier if they know this. I dont know.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here. But I also don't see how the web framework would help in any way. The problem is that you don't have a [mcve]. It's hard to guess what the problem is. Again, knowing the web framework will in no way change this. The HTML and JS code are needed - enough of them to recreate the issue you experience.

Comment: Ok thanks VLAZ, the form and html is rendered using Django Forms. So you'd need Python and Django to render as well as all the other Django code to make this reproducible. Maybe i could create some html as an example.

Comment: But as you said knowing the framework won't help. So ignoring everything else other than the JavaScript. 
Does this var event_form = document.getElementById("add-event"); only allow me to get elementIDs which only exisit within the "add-event"?

Comment: "*So you'd need Python and Django to render as well as all the other Django code to make this reproducible*" no, we just need some rendered HTML code. The code that generates it is not relevant. The example should be *minimal* as well as *reproducible*, so ignore anything that does not pertain to it. You have a problem with some HTML form and JavaScript that works with it. If the code that generated the form was PHP the problem would remain, because it is not down to *how* it is generated but *what* is generated and how JS works with it.